# Android square imageview

Tags: java, android, layout

im trying to make a table with square imageviews (and all with the same size). The problem is that the images have different height and width.
The table is 3x3 and i'd like to:
each cell have a with = 1/3 of the screen width (maybe with the layout weight?) and height =width
Much better if there is a way of define that in the xml than in code.
Please explain it because im a noob with layouts weights =(
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

Try the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) attribute. You want `centerCrop`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

well you can also use scaleType=fitXY to squeeze each image into the imageview's dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Extending imageveiw might be the cleanest solution. This works for me:

```
public class Icon extends ImageView {

public Icon(final Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Icon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Icon(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
        final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int width, int height) {
    super.onMeasure(width, height);
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    if (measuredWidth > measuredHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredHeight, measuredHeight);
    } else {
        setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredWidth);

    }

}

}
```

And in xml:

```
<com.your_package_name.Icon
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/screen" />
```